# Xcode UI Test record not generate script

Tags: xcode, xctest

I configure UI Tests. And I'm trying to record the UI test script.

And, the record button is enabled. But, when I tap the record button and do something active, not generate a test script.

This is a bug or am I wrong? Can you see the below link screen?

https://youtu.be/Xvy5LlkHp18

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this feature is broken in xcode 12.5. In 12.4 it works, try to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Xcode 12.5.1, so just update it.

[image: xcode changelog]